# Assigning cases to locations via Case Importer

Tags: commcare

How do you assign locations to cases when using the case importer?

Answer (score 3):

In order to have a case be owned by a location, you need to set the `owner_id` column in the Excel file being uploaded. This requires a two-step process.

#### Getting the location_id from your list of locations

To get the location id that you are looking for, you can bulk download your locations:

[image: screen shot]

Once you have the Excel file, you can open that up and you will find a column called `location_id`. This is the id you want when setting the `owner_id`.

#### Setting the owner_id of imported cases

If you have a location id (`my-location-id`) that you would like to have own a particular case, you can add this in your Excel file to import cases:

[image: sample Excel file]

Now when you import the cases, that case will be owned by the location specified in `owner_id`.